# Draw image on a MediaCapture in UWP application

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, uwp

Is it possible to draw an image over a CaptureElement or a MediaCapture instance? With the following code you get a nice video stream but is it possible to stream on image over it on every frame?

```
    mMediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
    await mMediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
    camera.Source = mMediaCapture;

    await mMediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Comment: Are you want to show static picture over your media capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your point, you can do it in XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <CaptureElement x:Name="camera"/>
    <!-- put your code over capture element -->
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/myImage.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oh that easy, I was thinking in way more complex terms. thanks!

Comment: This does not actually add an effect to the `MediaCapture`